# Autocomplete in sharepoint 2010 Visual webpart

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am working on a Visual web part in which I need to list matching data when user type something in text box (like in Google search or Question Title in StackOverflow).

I have ended up in lots of results, but it is for typical c# application.  I am looking for a solution which can be implemented directly in my visual web part.  I am using SharePoint 2010 and VS 2010.

I did the following things

Installed Ajax Control tool kit.
Added the Items to VS toolbox
and added the following code snippet.

in .ascx file

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMovie" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
    TargetControlID="txtMovie"  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    runat="server" UseContextKey="True" />
```

in .ascx.cs

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]      
public static string GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{           
    return "Hello";
}
```

But when I deployed I am getting this error

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

I removed the `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>` from my .ascx file however after that I am not able to edit my sharepint pages because of some js error.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What's the source of possible suggestions - a database table, a SharePoint list, a file? What part of this task is a problem for you - retrieving the items from source, showing a list below a textbox?

Comment: do you want to use web services to gain the data for the auto complete?

Comment: The data needs to be fetched from a Database table.  I have used Ajax ControlToolkit.  But still when I type something in text box nothing happens.

Comment: you can NOT use WebMethod in user control.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not working, came across a codeplex feature that will do the trick for you: http://spautocomplete.codeplex.com/

Also, check out this jQuery solution: http://sharepointwings.blogspot.in/2012/05/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-in.html

There is also one available from: Microsoft.Office.Search.WebControls.AutoCompleteExtender
regards,
KS